# Functions such that $f'(x)=f(cx)$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-equations

Let $c\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $|c|>1$. Does there exist functions $f\in\mathscr{C} ^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ such that $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}, \; f'(x) =f(cx)$ and $f\neq 0$ ? If yes, can we find all those functions ?

I have tried to search analytic such $f$, but the condition $|c|>1$ tells that no such functions exist.

I have tried to work with the Taylor expansion of a solution if there exists one...without success.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: @MartinR The accepted answer in that link shows that the Taylor series cannot converge. But that doesn't mean there is no $C^{\infty}$ function satisfying the given property, right?

Comment: Related questions: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/445951/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3626312/42969 – found [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24f%27(x)%3Df(cx)%24%2C%20AND%20site%3Amath.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: Yes, you are right (and I intentionally did not cast a duplicate vote because I had only a quick look at those threads). I have replaced that comment with another one. I would *assume* that this also has been asked and answered before, but have not found an identical question so far.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: What about this answer? https://math.stackexchange.com/a/445965/42969

Comment: @MartinR Only draw back is it defines $f$ only on $(0,\infty)$.

Comment: @MartinR : if moreover $f(0)=0$ is required?

Comment: @P.Fazioli: If $f(0) = 0$ and $0 < c < 1$ then $f$ is identically zero: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3453759/42969. – But that will probably not help here for the case $|c| > 1$.

Comment: just a side note: analytic or smooth? In general the notation $C^{\infty }$ is used for smooth functions. For analytic ones is used $C^{\omega }$ instead

Comment: @Masacroso : I mean $f$ smooth, i.e. $f^{(k)}$ exists for every $k$. The problem has no analytic solution $f$ if $|c|>1$.